# How to think about monthly subscriptions in Solana

Tags: anchor, anchor-lang, spl, subscription, month

I am looking to build a Monthly subscription program in anchor/Solana that allows a user to subscribe to a SPL token subscription (like USDC or SOL) such that the recipient automatically receives the SPL token at month end, OR has ownership of said funds.

I’m thinking of 2 methods at the moment:

1: create an escrow that allows a recipient to vest the funds monthly.

2: allow a program to have approve access to a user’s SPL token, have a cron job that runs once a month to transfer funds from user to recipient.

As a beginner, are these the only options to consider? Solution 1 requires a user to front capital into escrow which may be annoying. Solution 2 seems more ideal but I’m not sure how feasible it is - I come from EVM land where you can approve a token to be used / transferred by a smart contract.

Any tips / pointers greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Both approaches are valid and have their own advantages/drawbacks. One of the main limitation with delegates is that you can only have 1 delegate authority per token account.

You could potentially create custom token accounts which public keys are PDAs of your smart contract and the owner is the user. This way there will not be any collision between delegates on the ATA token account and the funds are still visible in the wallet but in a different (non ATA) token account

Comment: that makes sense, however in this case, don't I need to transfer the user's wrapped sol or USDC from their default ATA token account into the new one that is PDA?

How does Solana / anchor handle these type of wallets with multiple ATA token accounts? curious about the partition / ownership.

Comment: You would have to transfer the funds from the ATA to the non-ATA token account. The non-ATA token account public key would be a PDA of your smart contract, but the token account owner is the user not your smart contract, it's the user.

Wallets should be able to handle this well, in fact originally (back in 2020/2021) ATA did not exist and token accounts public key were not deterministic and many users had multiple token accounts for the same mint in their wallet. This should not be an issue at all for wallets